# RabbitMQ 3.7.8 AWS cluster formation plugin not found

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

We are trying to set up a rabbitmq cluster with the cluster formation plugins that ship with v3.7.8. We are using Ubuntu 16.04 and have erlang 21 installed.

I have tested the system with manual clusters and everything works fine.

The IAM roles are set with the correct policies and all of the required ports are open.

Enabling the rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws seems to work and I get the following response:

```
The following plugins have been configured:
  rabbitmq_management
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws
  rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@ip-10-0-0-192...
```

The problem comes when I add any command starting with cluster_formation.xxxx to the rabbit config file.

for example;

```
cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = rabbit_peer_discovery_aws

cluster_formation.aws.region = us-east-1
cluster_formation.aws.access_key_id = SOMERANDOMID
cluster_formation.aws.secret_key = somerandomkey

cluster_formation.aws.use_autoscaling_group = true
```

Restarting the rabbitmq service fails and the journalctl -xe states;

```
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
Oct 17 20:33:39 ip-10-0-0-192 rabbitmq-server[5868]: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: 24: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend: not found
Oct 17 20:33:39 ip-10-0-0-192 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Oct 17 20:33:39 ip-10-0-0-192 rabbitmqctl[5875]: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl: 24: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf: cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend: not found
Oct 17 20:33:39 ip-10-0-0-192 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Oct 17 20:33:39 ip-10-0-0-192 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
```

Anyway I change the the config file, if there is a command with cluster_formation at the start it will say that this command is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct configuration file name. Do these steps

```
mv /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

The [`rabbitmq-env.conf`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-env.conf.5.html) file is used to set the shell environment for RabbitMQ. [`rabbitmq.conf`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file) is the ini-style configuration file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can not let you know how much joy this comment has given me!